# AWS throws An Unknown error occurred while deploying API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, awsdeploy

In AWS API Gateway I am trying to deploy API to new stage, and im getting error "An unknown error occurred". I am assuming it most likely because of permission. But i have API Gateway administrator permissions.
How do find out exactly which permissions are missing? Does aws api gateway logs any deployment related events? Where do i find whats going on.

[image]

Comment: If you are on chrome or firefox open Develoepr tools(F12) and go to Network tab. Replicate the issue and see which AWS endpoint gave any error response.

Comment: that helped. It was actually throwing access denied error. `"__type":"AccessDeniedException","Message":"User: arn:aws:iam::xxxx:user/xxxxx is not authorized to perform: waf-regional:ListWebACLs on resource: arn:aws:waf-regional:us-west-2:xxxxx:webacl/*"}`

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html  enable core , its common issue .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering your question of Api Gateway deployment events, below are typical steps I do on what's happening.

1. Any operation you perform on Console or SDK is essentially calling AWS APIs.
2. For Console failures, you can always check on client side by going to Developer Tools provided by browsers. Typically `F12 key --> Network` tab, replicate the issue and see which AWS Endpoint gave error or go to `Console` tab and see any JavaScript errors logged.
3. If I am still not able to determine the cause, I enable [CloudTrail](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/) logs and see which user and which API call gave any error responses for which operation. CloudTrail Guide to [ApiGateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/cloudtrail.html).
4. If there is specific role or policy issue having issue, I use [Policy Simulator](https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/home/index.jsp?#) to test policies for the role once permissions are added.